# Wikipedia's definition of constant sheaf is wrong

Tags: sheaf-theory

According to wikipedia ([constant sheaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_sheaf)) the constant sheaf $\underline{S}$ for an object $S$ is given by defining $\underline{S}(U)$ to be the set of functions $U \to S$, which are constant on each connected component of $U$. I believe this is only true if $S$ is trivial (terminal object) or the space $X$ is locally connected. For example if $X$ is totally disconnected, then $\underline{S}(U)$ consists of all functions $U \to S$, and the canonical map $\underline{S}$ $_x \to S$ won't be injective.
I think that we have to define $\underline{S}(U)$ to be the set of locally constant functions $U \to S$. That is, continuous functions $U \to S$, where $S$ is endowed with the discrete topology. Since continuity is a local condition, this is a sheaf and it can be checked that the stalks are all $S$. This is the constant sheaf. Remark that locally constant functions are constant on each connected component, but the converse is not true. Interesting, in the wikipedia article about [sheaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf%5f%28mathematics%29) you can find the right definition.

Am I right or did I miss something?

Comment: Ok I left a remark on the discussion page. Too lazy to correct the article in a wikipedia-style ...

Comment: http://www.theonion.com/articles/factual-error-found-on-internet,102/

Comment: @Kevin Your onion plus one xkcd http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: I love this xkcd comic. however, this here is another situation because wikipedia is often a source for students who want to look up something quickly. for example when it was covered in a lecture, but without any explanation / formal definition. I agree that books are better. I already warned the students in my course ;).

Comment: Books also contain false definitions of constant sheaves. For example in Wells's "Differential analysis on complex manifolds", Prentice-Hall (1973), you can read page 39 (page 38 of the third edition : Springer, GTM 65, 2007), Example 1.6: "Let $X$ be a topological space and let $G$ be an abelian group. The assignment    $U \to G$ is a sheaf, called the constant sheaf" [ $U$ is a nonempty open set according to the context on page 38]. The word connected doesn't even appear. 

But it's a fine book all the same...


Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=vandalize+every+equation (Warning: many of the links contain content that may offend and is definitely not safe for work). As Vinge wrote, "It is not called the Net of a Million Lies for nothing."

Comment: The standard response to "Wikipedia is wrong": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:SOFIXIT

Comment: @Kevin This onion is perhaps also germane:
http://www.theonion.com/articles/wikipedia-celebrates-750-years-of-american-indepen,2007/

Comment: So I think it is clear by now that wikipedia is wrong, and that you are right.  I don't think anyone is going to post an answer to this question beyond what is already in the comments.  So shouldn't this question be closed?

Comment: Note however that wikipedia does manage to first give three correct definitions of the constant sheaf, which is more than most books do. It also tells you at the top of the page that the article has no references to back up any of its claims.

Comment: This question now has a meta thread - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/378/wikipedias-definition-of-constant-sheaf-is-wrong/

Comment: There's a cute utility at wikipedia that allows you to search article histories to locate when a certain phrase was inserted (it's called WikiBlame). This shows that the example originated with this edit (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sheaf_%28mathematics%29&diff=next&oldid=70699960) in the "Sheaf" article made by an anonymous IP user from the Univ. of Michigan in Aug. 2006. Isn't that fun?!

Comment: As an alternative to closing, one could phrase this question as a "reference request" for a counter-example to wikipedia's claim. One could then use this reference to improve wikipedia, a site that some people here clearly do find at least somewhat useful.

Comment: I voted to close because the question is no longer relevant (at least, for me) and basically the answer is already given in my question, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Voting to close as per Martin's previous comment.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard OK, but realistically people do expect Wikipedia to be right, and they expect maths textbooks to be right, and they expect the maths on Wikipedia to be right. It's up to people who know what a sheaf is (and what better forum to alert them) to correct WP, of course.